# Numeric Type Promotion with Conditional Expression

Tags: java, conditional-expressions

I was toying around with java, and I noticed something. It can be best shown here:

```
boolean boo = true;

Object object1 = boo ? new Integer(1) : new Double(2.0);

Object object2;
if (boo)
    object2 = new Integer(1);
else
    object2 = new Double(2.0);

System.out.println(object1);
System.out.println(object2);
```

I would expect the two to be the same, but this is what gets printed:

```
1.0
1
```

Does anyone have a good explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ternary must return the same type for both conditions, so your first result (`Integer`) is *promoted* to a double to match `2.0`. See also,

```
Object object1 = boo ? new Integer(1) : new Double(2.0);
System.out.println(object1.getClass().getName());
```

This is documented at [JLS-15.25.2 - Numeric Conditional Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2) which reads (in part)

> Otherwise, binary numeric promotion ([§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.
>
> *Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion ([§5.1.13](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.13)) and may perform unboxing conversion ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)).*

Comment: I'm not good in English. can you explain what is 'binary numeric promotion' ? and can you explain with example?

Comment: @UnKnown See the link to [JLS-5.6.2. Binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

Comment: Ok. But why Java convert them in ternary operator? any reason?

Answer (score 1):

JLS [section 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) has a [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-D) that summarizes the type of the conditional expression based on the type of its operands. For the case of `Integer` and `Double`, the table says that the type will be the result of applying binary numeric promotion to the arguments ([§15.25.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2))

> Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.
>
> *Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).*

Quoting [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>   
> ...
>   If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

---

This is what's happening for

```
Object object1 = boo ? new Integer(1) : new Double(2.0);
```

- The reference type `new Integer(1)` is unboxed to the primitive `int` 1.
- The reference type `new Double(2.0)` is unboxed to the primitive `double` 2.0.
- Binary numeric promotion is performed and the result is of type `double`. In this case, since `boo` is `true`, the primitive `int` 1 will be promoted to `double` as 1.0.
- Since you are storing the result in an `Object`, the primitive result is boxed into its wrapper type.

---

For the case of

```
Object object2;
if (boo)
    object2 = new Integer(1);
else
    object2 = new Double(2.0);
```

the if/else construct does not perform numeric promotion. In fact there won't be any boxing conversion. Since `boo` is `true`, the `if` part will be executed and `object2` will have the value `new Integer(1)`.