# Java Ternary Operations - Accepting Integer

Tags: java, conditional-operator

If I have Ternary syntax like this, compiler does not throw any compilation error:

```
int s = 2;
Double sdf = (s > 3 ?  new Double(12) : new Integer(12));
```

However if I have this, it is throwing compilation error:

> Required type: Double Provided: Integer

```
Double sdf = (s > 3 ?  new Integer(12) : new Integer(12));
```

Comment: Best practice dictates that ideally both branches of the ternary expression have the same type, and both also have the same type as the LHS.  As to why you are seeing this, it has to do with casting rules.  But, you should not rely on them anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - However, I am learning Java and experimenting to understand how Java works, so I am doing negative learning.

Comment: hope this helps too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694181/numeric-type-promotion-with-conditional-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because if we use wrapped primitive values like in the question (`Integer`, `Float`, `Double` etc.) in a ternary operator, both values will be **unboxed and coerced** to a common type.

This may result in unexpected results as well.

In the first example, `new Integer(12)` would be converted to a `double` as it is the common type. Hence there are no compilation issue.

But in the second example both are `Integer` which is not compatible with the left hand side type `Double`.

Example taken from Sonar rule description `S2154`:

```java
Integer i = 123456789;
Float f = 1.0f;
// Assume condition = true
Number n = (condition) ? i : f; // i is coerced to float. n = 1.23456792E8
```

To fix this, we need to do explicit casting:

```java
Integer i = 123456789;
Float f = 1.0f;
// Assume condition = true
Number n = condition ? (Number) i : f;  // n = 123456789
```

Additional suggestion: Do not use `new Double()` or `new Integer()` etc. These constructors are deprecated. Instead use `valueOf` method

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Conditional Operator ? : specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), in case if one operand is `Integer` and the other is `Double` [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is used to resolve the result type.

Based on the rules, in the first example, the result type is `Integer` but `Double` in the second one (unboxing + widening).

Answer (score 1):

It's because internally type is pramoted. Integer can be pramoted to double. But double can't be demoted to Integer.
Pramotion happens in following way
Byte -->Short-->Interger-->Long-->Float -->Double